# UICollectionView random cell fitting

Tags: ios, swift2, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

Given a list of variable length words what is the best way to organize them in a UICollectionView with a maximum of 3 cells a line so that they fit in the best way possible. 
I. E a longer word would be in a row by itself but 3 shorter words can be in the same time